# Is it possible to split a PDF into separate files based on text using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a large single pdf document which consists of multiple records. Each record usually takes one page however some use 2 pages. A record starts with a defined text, always the same.

My goal is to split this pdf into separate pdfs and the split should happen always before the "header text" is found.

Comment: You can achieve this with [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/5.5.13.1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

### TikaOnDotnet

Take a look at TikaOnDotnet.TextExtractor it's a wrapper around the Tika text extraction Java library.

You can get data from your pdf easy like that:

```
var text = new TextExtractor().Extract(file.FullName).Text;
```

**docs:** https://github.com/KevM/tikaondotnet

**nuget:** https://www.nuget.org/packages/TikaOnDotnet.TextExtractor/

---

### itext7

You can also use itext7

**docs:** https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.1.9/index.html

**nuget:** https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/